# How to avoid using a subquery for exclusion in a many-to-many sql model?

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, many-to-many, window-functions

Let's say we have a model with posts and tags with a many to many relationship.

For example :

**Posts** table

| Id | Title | HtmlContent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat eating a cucumber | ... |
| 2 | Chicken flying above a cucumber | ... |
| 3 | Cucumber taking revenge | ... |

**Tags** table

| Id | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat |
| 2 | chicken |
| 3 | vegetables |
| 4 | funny |

**PostsTags** association table

| Id | PostId | TagId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

Yesterday my objective was to find the number of `Posts` not involving a cat nor being funny (i.e. I don't want `Posts` having a connection with `Tags` 1 or 4).

The query I came up with was this one :

```
select count(p.Id)
from posts p
where p.Id not in (
    select postid 
    from poststags 
    where TagId in (1, 4)
    group by postid
)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to exclude posts in the many-to-many relationship without executing any subquery ?

FYI I am using an SQLite database.

Comment: You can use left join. Anyway you need both tables taking part in the query. What's wrong with your current version?

Comment: @Serg I am fine with the current version, I just want to know if there are more clever techniques :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and window function `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(CASE WHEN SUM(tagid IN (1, 4)) = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER ()
FROM PostsTags
GROUP BY postid
```

Or, window function `SUM()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(SUM(tagid IN (1, 4)) = 0) OVER ()
FROM PostsTags
GROUP BY postid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=00c453b7bae27c2e918014a5a34e3eca).

Comment: I did not know about window functions, thanks a lot ! Do you know if performance is better than the one with my subquery ?

Comment: @Sbu the performance of NOT IN gets worse as the size of the resultset in the subquery increases. For a relatively small dataset I don't think that it would make any difference. If you find your query more readable and understandable and you don't have a large table keep it as it is.

Comment: Do you know why I can't simply nest the `SUM` without using the window frame in your second query ? What is the rule that allows us to use a window function but not the SUM aggregation a second time ?

Comment: @Sbu it's not allowed to nest one aggregate function inside another. This is the rule in SQL. If you want to aggregate on the results of an aggregate function you must use subqueries. But you can nest an aggregate function inside a window function. Moreover you can't nest a window function inside another window function.